# MVC Error when accessing forms based authentication database using two projects in one solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I am trying to build a complicated web project that involves 4 websites that all share the same models, database and also use the built-in forms based authentication.

It was previosuly been suggested to me to create a class library which contains the shared elements and then to reference that library in each of my projects. This makes sense to me but I seemed to run into a lot of errors even after getting all the references included. So I basically started from scratch and now I have two regular MVC 4.0 projects under one solution. The first project is working fine. It contains the forms based authenticxation membership controllers and models as well as all my data models and the App_Data folder with the db inside. The web.config file points to the DB and I have absilute no problems testing the Membership featues with the default view and controllers supplied.

I have set a depndency on the second app on the first and referenced the first project as well. This project contains only default HomeController and Views. I get no errors on build. When I go to run the webite and then try to access /Account/LogOff for example, I receive the following error:

Cannot attach the file '~\App_Data\Pp.mdf' as database 'Pp.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot attach the file '~\App_Data\Pp.mdf' as database 'Pp.

Source Error:

Line 39:                     }
Line 40: 
Line 41: WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("PpDB", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true); Line 42:                 }
Line 43:                 catch (Exception ex)

Source File: c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Prp\PpModels\Filters\InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs    Line: 41

I tried playing with the second project's connection string but I'm really not sure how the paths get resolved using MVC.

Any help and advice would be appreciated. I am pulling my hair out! If you kow f any tutorials that show you how to use multiple projects sharing models and DB's that would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to hard code the full path within the connection string in the second project so that it points to the app_data folder in the first project.